# Facebook login (web) can't see users logged in by the facebook device app

Tags: php, javascript, ios, facebook, authentication

I have a facebook web login page, and when you already loggin in with facebook you don't have to log in anymore with you're account.

Now the problem is when I open the website on a iPad/iPhone and on the device I'm already logged in with the facebook app. My site can't see this and will ask you to log in via safari again.

I tried to use the Facebook JavaScript and PHP SDK, and both can't find an account logged in on the app. any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are two different sessions. The app and the actual website must share the same session but this is not really a good idea security wise, and I am not sure if it is even possible.